# Matrix multiplication for higher dimensional matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix like this (myb1):

[image: myb1 matrix output]

I would like to get the matrix multiplication of each of the submatrix to itself. For example the first $2\times2$ matrix 
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$
 should be multiplied by itself and answer of `res2[[1, 1]]` be $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 6\\3 & 6\end{bmatrix}$ and so on.

I tried:
for loop (in the picture) and didn't help

Direct *Mathematica* code: `myb1.myb1` and it didn't work out either

#### Mathematica Code

```
myb1[[1, 1]] = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}

myb1[[1, 2]] = {{2, 3}, {3, 4}}

myb1[[2, 1]] = {{5, 2}, {8, 2}}

myb1[[2, 2]] = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}

For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,

 For[j = 1, j <= 2, j++,

  res2 = myb1[[i, j]].myb1[[i, j]];

  ]

 ]
```

Comment: Here is a link to a FAQ post that explains why it's typically a bad idea to use `MatrixForm`, no matter how alluring its nicely formatted output might be: [(18393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB: removed unwanted edits to abate duplication

Comment: You will still want to avoid using MatrixForm as you are showing. If you absolutely need to have pretty-printed matrices, then at least use: `(myb1 = {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}) // MatrixForm;`. Note the () brackets: they change the order of execution so that the variable `myb1` is assigned the "raw" matrix, *before* the `MatrixForm` is evaluated.

Comment: to clarify here, `MatrixForm` is a *display* function. it's used to show your results as a matrix, but is not used during calculations. you don't need to tell Mathematica "hey this is a matrix" because any rectangular list of lists is as good a matrix as you need. for example `Det[{{a, 1}, {Graphics[Disk[]], d}}]` will give an answer. this is a deliberate design feature. in particular, it means that all the functions you use for dealing with lists (such as `Reverse`) can also be used directly on matrices... and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you again for your response @MarcoB , removed matrix form from code as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the love of this fine site, please post copyable code along with accompanying images the next time!

Anyway:

```
myb1 = {{{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}}},
        {{{5, 2}, {8, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}}};

Map[MatrixPower[#, 2] &, myb1, {2}]
   {{{{3, 6}, {3, 6}}, {{13, 18}, {18, 25}}},
    {{{41, 14}, {56, 20}}, {{3, 6}, {3, 6}}}}

Map[#.# &, myb1, {2}]
   {{{{3, 6}, {3, 6}}, {{13, 18}, {18, 25}}},
    {{{41, 14}, {56, 20}}, {{3, 6}, {3, 6}}}}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion -- can you look at my edit and tell me how to get the final answer instead of dots between matrices inside the big matrix

Comment: Yes: **don't use `MatrixForm[]`**. Then, try again.